# animate div's from one position to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

i have a scenario where when click a button the div should move from one offset position to another and i am finding out offset of an element in this way

```
function getOffset(el) {
   el = el[0].getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
     left: el.left + window.scrollX,
     top: el.top + window.scrollY
   }
}
var _anchorElemPos = getOffset($element)//$element is the element to which the animation should happen
```

and for animation i am going for :

```
_animationElement.animate(_targetAnimPos);
```

here `_targetAnimPos` is the target position

but here .animate() is jquery function and i dont want to use jquery is there any other way to have exact animation like .animate() using javascript ?
I dont have to use jquery in my application

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how about change id or class element name that point to css3 animation

Comment: @areiilla
Could u please demo it?
i even have to show that div moving based on position it should move to that position